# What web server configuration is required to make AngularJS routing function correctly?

Tags: caching, angularjs, routes, timestamp, infinite-loop

I am using AngularJS routing to provide a single page application.  The configuration is:

```
var ewiApp = angular.module("ewi", []);
ewiApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home',
        {
            templateUrl: '/private/app/index.html'
        });
    $routeProvider.when('/alarms/active',
        {
            templateUrl: '/private/app/alarms/partials/active.html',
            controller:  'ActiveAlarmListCtrl'
        });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
});
```

The problem that I am experiencing is that when I type "/" or "/abc" or anything other than "/alarms/active", the angularjs library goes into an infinite loop trying to load the index.html file and all of its javascript, css, and image files over and over again.  I notice that a timestamp has been added to each file request.  I seems as though angularjs is trying to not use the cached versions of the files that have already been loaded. This continues forever until I close the browser tab.

I am including the following javascript libraries as well as some of our own:

```
<script src="/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

I've watched a few online videos that discuss how to set up AngularJS routing and they all mention that some server configuration is also required, but I have not seen anything that identifies specifically what the server configuration needs to be.  I'm wondering if my problem with the infinite loop within the angularjs library has something to do with something that I need to change on the server?  I am using a lighttpd web server.

I'm wondering if anyone else has run into this issue?

Comment: What version of Angular?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS v1.0.7

Comment: I just tried AngularJS v1.1.5 and the infinite loop file reloading problem still exists.

Comment: You'll have to put this in a Plunkr for people to actually see the running code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel stupid, but I found out the cause of the AngularJS library going into an infinite loop when the the "/home" URL is entered or the "otherwise" clause was triggered.

The problem was due to my specification for the templateURL for the following statement:

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: '/private/app/index.html'
});
```

Since the main (single page) page was already the "/private/app/index.html" file, this specification caused the contents of the "index.html" file to be loaded into the <ng-view> tag section of the same file.  This then caused all of the links specified to be re-loaded, and then <ng-view> tag within the included page caused a request to load another "index.html" page, over-and-over again.

The fix was to change the code above to:

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: '/private/app/home/partials/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl"
});
```

Now everything works correctly for each of the specified "when()" URLs, the "/home" URL, and any bogus URL (like "/abcdef".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that this is the issue, but generally I don't put ; after each route. Just chain them like this:

```
var ewiApp = angular.module("ewi", []);
ewiApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home',
    {
        templateUrl: '/private/app/index.html'
    })
    .when('/alarms/active',
    {
        templateUrl: '/private/app/alarms/partials/active.html',
        controller:  'ActiveAlarmListCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home' })

});
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but the infinite reloading issue still exists.

Comment: Interesting and you have a REST server set up?  Or is that the server config you are talking about?

Comment: I don't think that my server is a REST server.  The videos on AngularJS routing that I've watched say that the server must be set up to serve the index.html file when a URL not setup in the AngularJS $routeProvider.when() calls is specified.  I'm not sure exactly what I need to do on the server.  Right now it is returning the contents of the index.html file when an unknown URL is specified.  I noticed that redirecting to the index.html file did not work so I'm just returning the file for any unknown request.